# Where Does A Label & Description For A Custom Permission Defined In The Manifest Get Displayed On A Device?

Tags: android

So the application element definition in a manifest, if you give that a label attribute, that shows up in a number of places.

Labels on custom permissions, I'm not seeing where that shows up in Lollipop.

Comment: In theory, it should show up when you install another app that has the corresponding `<uses-permission>` element.